# How to get count of number of records group by and grand total count in report

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to get count of records for each group by and then final total count at the end.

For example, I have a report which is group by User for each Shipments. I want to get count of shipments for each user.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, you can set ResetGroup field to the group you want to reset, for the Variable you created. This should recount the variable for each group.